# What Causes MySQLNonTransientConnectionException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

In my application which is using DBCP for connection pooling, and I am getting the below Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up
```

Can anybody tell me what are the scenarios in which this Exception occurs? Also in this situation, DBCP hangs and further processing not done.

Comment: Could you show us the connection link?

Comment: its standalone application, what type of connection link u need

Comment: I mean the connection URL you pass to the JDBC driver to establish the connection.

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace

Comment: Cleaned up the formatting and grammar just a bit.